# monaco-editor - suggestion details widget (opened by suggestion list) - change placement

Tags: monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I'm using monaco-editor 0.45.0 and
I want to change the placement of the suggestion details widget to be always below the suggestion list.

how it behaves today:
[details opened to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85sEP.png)

desired behavior: (achieved by resizing the page width to be thinner)
[details opened below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YWWX.png)

I use a low version (0.18) of monaco-editor and there I could manipulate with css to get what I want.
Now (not sure since which version) the details widget placement is set by fixed position with calculated left and top - this can't be workaround by css as I tried.

Can you help me achieve the desired functionality?